# Why float numbers (when typed in shell) has an additional digits (zeros)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new in python and I was typing float numbers in python2.7 shell when I figured this:

```
>>> 9.9
9.9000000000000004
>>> 9.9==_
True
>>> 9.9==9.90000004
False
>>> 7.7
7.7000000000000002
>>> 7.7==_
True
>>> 7.7==7.700000002
False
```

my question is, why does 9.9 became 9.900000000000004? Is it default?

Please let me know if this is a duplicate. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it is due to the binary nature of the computers. This is not a Python specific issue. The fractional part cannot always be exactly represented in binary numbers. Read about [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) and check examples&solid explanation [here](http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/43).